# Ranking a list without breaking ties in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, ranking

I need to attribute ranks to elements of a list while making sure tied elements get the same rank.

For instance:

```
data = [[1],[3],[2],[2]]

c = 0

for i in sorted(data, reverse=True):
    i.append(c+1)
    c += 1

print data
```

returns:

```
[[1, 4], [3, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Where a rank is appended to the score.

What would I need to change to this simple code to instead obtain:

```
[[1, 3], [3, 1], [2, 2], [2, 2]]
```

Where elements scoring 2 are tied and both obtain the second place, while 1, the previously fourth place, is promoted to third place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> data = [[1],[3],[2],[2]]
>>> sorted_data = sorted(data, reverse=True)
>>> for rank, (_, grp) in enumerate(groupby(sorted_data, key=lambda xs: xs[0]), 1):
...     for x in grp:
...         x.append(rank)
...
>>> print data
[[1, 3], [3, 1], [2, 2], [2, 2]]
```

Comment: Could grouby be adjusted to produce [[1, 4], [3, 1], [2, 2], [2, 2]] ?
(where elements scoring 2 are tied and both obtain the second place,  while 1 stays the fourth place)

Comment: @Rodolphe, See this: http://pastebin.com/ci8eqnWe . If you have more question, please post a separate question.

Comment: Thanks once again! Thanks for the advice on further questions